# Capture specific Internal Server Errors in Mod_perl

Tags: perl, mod-perl

My perl application currently has basic logging. I am using Mod_perl and CGI

When an error occurs in the script the user gets an internal server error page. I know that CPAN CGI has an error reporting feature, but this feature seems to be for a individual script. What I wanted was to capture a stack trace globally and then report it to the user on a webpage. so that when this happens the user gets a nice 'something went wrong' page rather than a clueless Internal Server Error page.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this nicely by creating bootstrap.pl script. I redirected with mod_rewrite all scripts to bootstrap.pl and posted actual url as parameter. In bootstrap I am handling sessions, logging, etc and in the end I am calling eval('script from url'). The most interesting for you is error handling:

```
use ex::override GLOBAL_die => sub {
    my $stackTrace = Devel::StackTrace->new(no_refs => 1)->as_string;
    if ($stackTrace =~ /eval \{/) {
            CORE::die @_;
    } else {
            local *__ANON__ = "Exception";
            select STDOUT;
            print getError500( sprintf(
                                    join("\n",<DATA>),
                                    @_,
                                    $stackTrace,
                                    Dumper(\%ENV)
            ));
            CORE::exit 1;
    }
```

};

This is overwriting die and printing nice error 500 page with full stack on exception. I tried many things and this looks like the best approach for me.